# Scrape xlf file in python with ElementTreee

Tags: python, xml

I have a lot of .xlf files to modify.
I've found and replace almost all entries automatically via ElementTree in python but I cannot access to some of them. Those which are unreachable are all like this :

```
<xliff>
<file>
<body>
<group>
<trans-unit>
<source>
<g ctype="x-html-p" id="1" dgo:tag_name="p">Saisis, pour cet exemple, 
<g ctype="x-html-span" id="2" htm:font-weight="bold" dgo:tag_name="span" dgo:span_type="0">
<ph dgo:ph_type="#" dgo:ph_name="text_d" ctype="x-dgo-ph" id="3"/></g> 
dans le champ 
<g ctype="x-html-span" id="4" htm:font-weight="bold" dgo:tag_name="span" dgo:span_type="0">
SET
</g> 
de la ligne 
<g ctype="x-html-span" id="5" htm:font-weight="bold" dgo:tag_name="span" dgo:span_type="0">
<ph dgo:ph_type="#" dgo:ph_name="fieldname" ctype="x-dgo-ph" id="6"/> <ph dgo:ph_type="I" dgo:ph_name="fieldicon" ctype="x-dgo-ph" id="7"/></g>.
</g><g ctype="x-html-p" id="8" dgo:tag_name="p"> </g>
</source>
</trans-unit>
</group>
</source>
</body>
</file>
</xliff>
```

To be honest, I can get the first entry, here "Saisis, pour cet exemple" by calling g.text (source's child) but other entries are unreachable (" dans le champ ", "SET", ...).

Any idea ?

By advance, thanks a lot,

Mich

edit :
Code example (I'm a bit newbie in python !)

```
if child.tag == "group":
        for bchild in child:
            if bchild.tag == "trans-unit":
                for bch in bchild:
                    if bch.tag == "source":
                        source = bch.text
                        if source is None:
                            for tchild in bch:
                                g = tchild.text
                                if g is None:
                                    for ttchild in tchild:
                                        try:
                                            g = ttchild.text
```

edit 2 :
Here a bit of xlf file with header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2 xliff-core-1.2-transitional.xsd" xmlns:htm="urn:datango:xsd:xliff:htm" xmlns:dgo="urn:datango:xsd:xliff:dgo" version="1.2"><file original="project!PR_5A946F57615660AF" datatype="x-datango-tour-project" tool-id="SAP Enable Now Producer" product-name="SAP project" product-version="10.5.2" source-language="es-ES" targetlanguage="es-ES"><header><tool tool-id="SAP Enable Now Producer" tool-name="SAP Enable Now Producer" tool-version="10.5.2" tool-company="SAP"/></header><body><trans-unit id="project!PR_5A946F57615660AF:macro!MAC_8C82245EA1E1BF92:.explanation_p" datatype="htmlbody" restype="x-dgo-HTML"><source><g ctype="x-html-p" id="1" dgo:tag_name="p">Clique sur le champ <g ctype="x-html-span" id="2" htm:font-weight="bold" dgo:tag_name="span" dgo:span_type="0">SET</g> de la ligne <g ctype="x-html-span" id="3" htm:font-weight="bold" dgo:tag_name="span" dgo:span_type="0"><ph dgo:ph_type="#" dgo:ph_name="fieldname" ctype="x-dgo-ph" id="4"/> <ph dgo:ph_type="I" dgo:ph_name="fieldicon" ctype="x-dgo-ph" id="5"/></g>.</g></source><target><g ctype="x-html-p" id="1" dgo:tag_name="p">Clique sur le champ <g ctype="x-html-span" id="2" htm:font-weight="bold" dgo:tag_name="span" dgo:span_type="0">SET</g> de la ligne <g ctype="x-html-span" id="3" htm:font-weight="bold" dgo:tag_name="span" dgo:span_type="0"><ph dgo:ph_type="#" dgo:ph_name="fieldname" ctype="x-dgo-ph" id="4"/> <ph dgo:ph_type="I" dgo:ph_name="fieldicon" ctype="x-dgo-ph" id="5"/></g>.</g></target></trans-unit></group></body></file></xliff>
```

Comment: can you please use English?

Comment: can you give an example (based on the xml you have shared) of something that you want to replace and fail to do it?

Comment: In fact, I need to retrieve the data first.
Replacing is easy when I have the right tag to use.

Comment: your xml is not VALID. Please upload a valid one.

Comment: Here you are, I made some separations to ease the reading. xlf files comes in a single line.

Comment: Use xpath to find elements by searching for a nesting of tags/attributes - read the documentation it's not so difficult to use but for a long xpath start simple and add more steps so if it doesn't find an element you know it was the step you just added that you need to fix. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=xpath#xpath-support - also for example dans le champ is the .tail of the ph tag. SET is the .text of the g tag it is contained in.

Comment: No, "dans le champ" is the `tail` of the second `<g>` element.

Comment: Please post **one** representative, well-formed XML document. The second XML document does not include the phrase "dans le champ". It is also unclear what you want to do. What does "Scrape xlf file" mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks balmy,
by working with tails and stronger XPath, it worked better.

Have a nice day !